# Missing indicator in XL4016 buck converter module

Tags: power-supply, indicator, module

I’ve bought below XL4016e1 buck module. There is an empty spot between the `Indicator light` and `Input negative`, between the left most capacitors.

- What component is missing there? an LED/buzzer/adjustment POT?
- What it supposed to do/indicate? Short circuit, No load, Over-under voltage, output lower than battery voltage, or some calibration?

From the backside it looks like one end is connected to `Output negative`

[image]
[image]

---

I couldn’t find a shop on the Internet providing this information. Some versions of this module seem to have left this spot blank on PCB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just a spot for an LED with a series resistor (probably also not fitted, on the opposite side of the PCB and mostly obscured by the heat sink in your photo) connected across the output.

Not very vital. The bicolor LED already provides input power and overload indication. Unlike the latter, the brightness would vary with output voltage adjustment.

Comment: Ahh, so it’s a presense of output indicator when the device is used without a voltemeter. How can I make an indicator that will work with 3-36v range? Using 3 LEDs and 12v, 24v zener diodes and resistors?